# Text of python scripts is shown in browser instead or running them

Tags: python, apache

I have apache2 running on my ubuntu 14.04. The configuration for the virtual host is

```
 `ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/(path to some myfolder)/cgi-bin/
  <Directory "/home/(path to some myfolder)/cgi-bin">
      DirectoryIndex index.py
      Options +ExecCGI
      AddHandler cgi-script .py
      Require all granted
 </Directory>`
```

Then index.py is not running as well as any other python script. Instead the text of the scripts is shown in the browser window.

I also tried to stop apache and use python -m CGIHTTPServer instead, but with the same result.

Also, the command chmod +x index.py was routinely applied to all python scripts I tried.

To run the script I used the url: 127.0.0.1/index.py, though I also tried
127.0.0.1:80/index.py and 127.0.0.1:80/(the whole pathe to the file in the cgi-bin folder)

I use port 80.

The script I use to test is

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
print "Content-type: text/html"
print "Hello, World."
```

python2.7 is in the folder /usr/bin so the path is correct

The best I found on the Internet were advices implemented under Directory tag above. Bwt, the result does not change if I launch the scripts in browsers as root. I tried Firefox and Chrome, all the same.

The question is how to make my python scripts run in a browser?

Comment: What is the URL you enter into the web browser to access the page? Can you show me a sample Python script?

Comment: Does the `index.py` have the executable flag set?

Comment: @GreenIslander Please edit your question and add everything you've put in the comments so far.

Comment: Why do you think apache must to run this script? Read about mod_wsgi, mod_python and how setup apache + python

Comment: @AlexanderRavikovich because I am trying to simulate server side python script. Do you mean I can run this script in the browser without using any server?

Comment: No. I mean you need tell to Apache how to work with .py files. You need install mod_wsgi or mod_python (too old). Read about Python for web in python's website.

Comment: @AlexanderRavikovich looking at http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod_wsgi.    it says mod _wsgi is an alternative to cgi, but I am already using cgi and looks like using correctly, but something still does not work

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html -> Common problems with CGI scripts. Try this solutions.

Comment: @AlexanderRavikovich I saw this text and tried all. does not work for me